# trying to import json data on PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to import data on PostgreSQL

in my PostgreSQL table column includes

```
ojbectId (text)
createdAt (timestamptz)
updatedAt (timestamptz)
radius (float8)
pos (jsonb)
theta (float8)
cpId (text)
type (float8)
isRestricted (float8)
```

and my test json file includes

```
{
"ptest": [
    {
        "objectId" : "abc",
        "createdAt" : "2022-05-06T02:34:21.229Z",
        "updatedAt" : "2022-05-06T02:34:21.229Z",
        "radius" : 1.0,
        "theta" : 180.0,
        "attributes" : "{}",
        "cpId" : "abcd",
        "name" : "{\"en\": \"\", \"kr\": \"\", \"en-US\": \"\", \"ko-KR\": \"\"}",
        "pos" : "{\"x\": 62.35, \"y\": 25.1}",
        "isRestricted" : 0.0,
        "type" : 600.0
    },
    {
        "objectId" : "def",
        "createdAt" : "2022-05-06T02:34:38.311Z",
        "updatedAt" : "2022-05-06T02:34:38.311Z",
        "radius" : 1.0,
        "theta" : 180.0,
        "attributes" : "{}",
        "cpId" : "efgh",
        "name" : "{\"en\": \"\", \"kr\": \"\", \"en-US\": \"\", \"ko-KR\": \"\"}",
        "pos" : "{\"x\": 33.81, \"y\": 16.9}",
        "isRestricted" : 0.0,
        "type" : 600.0
    },
```

I tried to import this json file into PSQL command by

```
cat temp.json | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c "COPY ptest (objectId, createdAt, updatedAt, radius, theta, attributes, cpid, name, pos, isRestricted, type) FROM STDIN;"
```

from those json file, I directly parsed my column names, but the error occurs with
"cloumn objectId" of relation "ptest" does not exist

I tried to find multiple exmaples for importing psql data with json.
https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/fast-csv-and-json-ingestion-in-postgresql-with-copy

only this link was closest with my command, and I also couldn't solve this problem

How should I fix my psql command to input data?

Comment: `psql` can't just import a JSON file and magically map JSON keys to column names. You will need to first convert the JSON to e.g. a CSV format. Or put the **whole** JSON into a single column of a temporary table, then use the built-in functions to convert the JSON to a proper relational representation

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought converting data was quite simple (from the link I attached). Then importing CSV format data is recommandable?

Comment: Well, the import the JSON "as-is" and apparently also have one line per JSON in the input file. You seem to want to convert an array of JSON values to rows where the keys represent columns. That is something completely different

Comment: I realized the type of json file I was trying to import  and json file created from the link was different with row. I should find more informations. Thank you for the information. Have a nice day